# Control motors drone

Tags: ros, rospackage, pixhawk

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm planning to control a drone via a ROS-framework through the Pixhawk flight controller. But I'm wondering if there are packages which will let me able to control the drones motors.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275635/control-motors-drone/) by [MaximeRector](https://answers.ros.org/users/29590/maximerector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've used the [`mavros` package](http://wiki.ros.org/mavros) with the pixhawk and is quite nice. Lots of people use it and I believe that there also tutorials for it on the pixhawk site too.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MaximeRector](https://answers.ros.org/users/29590/maximerector/) on 2017-11-13**:
I have seen something of it, but I wasn't sure if it is also possible for example move the drone 10 cm to the right without using gps

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-13**:
Yes, it supports waypoint navigation. Check out the link to the wiki that I posted.